# How do I use the [subpaths] section in .hgsub to remap a local subrepo for use in bitbucket

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

> > **NOTE:** Since I'm new they won't let me post links, which means all the config files will have improperly formatted URLs. This is simply to get around stackoverflow's limitations, I have used the correct URL in practice.

I tried to setup a subrepo, let's call it A/B. So that cloning works properly, I wanted a normal relative path to put it inside the repository, so logically I had `.hgsub`:

```
A/B = A/B
```

However when trying to push this into bitbucket I get the usual 404 (NOT FOUND) error because on bitbucket B cannot be local, and is actually another project (http s://username@bitbucket.org/username/B)

So then I said, OK just to make bitbucket work I can put `.hgsub`:

```
A/B = https://username@bitbucket.org/username/B
```

However, I recently found out that supposedly there was a workaround here: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepository where you use the `[subpaths]` section so that cloning locally works normal, but bitbucket will request the special path for the project.

So I tried copying their instructions. `.hgsub:`

```
A/B = A/B
[subpaths]
https://username@bitbucket.org/username/project/A/B = https://username@bitbucket.org/username/B
```

But I get the same 404 error. Supposedly whenever it sees `https://username@bitbucket.org/username/project/A/B`, it will instead remap to the latter `https://username@bitbucket.org/username/B` which will work. However, this doesn't appear to be the case. I have also tried without putting the `username@` at the beginning.

Any help would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: The feature is apparently really recent. The mail linked in the documentation is dated 11 october 2011. Are you sure the version of Mercurial you're using is recent enough to support this ?

Comment: I am using Mercurial 2.0, and bitbucket is on 1.9. I looked up when the changelog history for mercurial: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/WhatsNew and it was supposedly added in 1.7 unless I'm misreading it.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I think I was testing at a different repo so it wasn't grabbing the match. Here's the working config for all those interested:

.hgsub:

> A/B = A/B
>
> [subpaths]
>
> bitbucket\.org/username/projectname/A/B = bitbucket.org/username/B

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `subpaths` config is incorrect.  The string on the left side must be a pattern that matches an entry in your `.hgsub`.  I think you want something like:

```
[subpaths]
A/B = https://username@bitbucket.org/username/B
```

More info may be found in:

- [SubrepoRemappingPlan](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/SubrepoRemappingPlan)
- The `subpaths` section of [`hg help hgrc`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/config):

Here is an excerpt from the `hgrc` help:

> Defines subrepositories source locations rewriting rules of the form:
>
> ```
>   <pattern> = <replacement>
>
> Where "pattern" is a regular expression matching the source and
> "replacement" is the replacement string used to rewrite it. Groups can be
> matched in "pattern" and referenced in "replacements". For instance:
>
>   http://server/(.*)-hg/ = http://hg.server/\1/
>
> rewrites "http://server/foo-hg/" into "http://hg.server/foo/".
> ```

Comment: That doesn't work (doing that will make it look for https://username@bitbucket.org/username/project/https://username@bitbucket.org/username/B - with the colon escaped). But your answer made me fiddling around in a way that I figured it out - thanks!